# I have written my project in cordova. Can I convert it or run it in IOS?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

The app is a simple login interface. I am new to hybrid development and want to test my work in IOS interface.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can do this same as Android.**

**Just open your CLI.**

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

Here replace id and project name as per your requirement.

**Go to this project directory using below `Command`.**

```
cd hello

cordova platform add ios

cordova prepare ios
```

**You project is created and you can open it with XCode.**

Then if you have already working project in `Android` and if you want to make workable in `IOS`.

Just copy all files of your `Root->WWW->` to Ios Project.

**For reference see this.**

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/cli/

Comment: Thanks for the help but when i apply, 

cordova run ios

It gives me error "xcodebuild was not found"

Comment: @Nirman Their is no any cordova run ios command . what you are trying . Have you followed above full process.

Comment: Ok @jaydroider but even on running cordova build ios/ cordova compile ios, I am getting the same error.

Comment: @Nirman What is the problem can u explain so that i can suggest you.

Comment: @Nirman Do you able to create project successfully on your CLI ? Could you post whatever you have tried on CLI.

Comment: I have mobiles from both platforms. The android platform is running fine with "cordova run android" but after installing ios platform when i write cordova build ios it gives me "xcodebuild not found" error.

Comment: @Nirman Can u try with only giving `Cordova Build` don't write ios and let me know. And make sure are you applying this command in your project directory means for e.g cd hello.

Comment: @Nirman please specify something more with CLI log or explain more on which step you are getting this exception.

Comment: Hey @jaydroider, let me tell you what all I executed.
- cordova platform add ios 
- cordova build

After it, I get the message of "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" with the earlier specified error at bottom.

Comment: Do I have to create a virtual OS X for my app to run in IOS??

Comment: @Nirman Error is showing that's right but Have you tried to open project with Xcode and check in simulator that app is running or not ?

Comment: this is where i need assistance. Can you explain me how to work with Xcode. I am fairly new to hybrid development and my current OS is windows 7.

Comment: @Nirman Ooops yes you need either MAC or if windows os then OS X need to be installed to working with ios. You can't directly do that.

Comment: thanks for that @jaydroider, let me install and check if it works.

Comment: @Nirman Let me know is it worked for you with all suggested things ?